# Best way to send .zips to an Android app from a server

Tags: android, json, http, zip

I am designing an application that will **retrieve .zip files from a server** and **extract them to the sdcard** on reception.

I think i can figure out the extracting, but I am not sure what the best way to send the .zips from the server is. It only need to be one way for now but in the future I would like to add version control if that matters.

I did some research and looked into JSON but I could not find any examples of that sending .zip files. A http connection seems like a comparable option and I know I could receive .zips but I don't think version control would be as easy to implement. Any suggestions for either of these two methods or if you think another way would be better, I'm open to that too.

Comment: JSON is a data format that is sent via HTTP connection. Where are your zip files stored (http server, ftp server, something else)? If it is an http server, are you using standard http, asp.net, java?

Comment: I would like to use http just because i think it would be easier to implement but if using java or something else would be more useful i could use that too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a manifest file and get that first. Examine the manifest file (a file that contains a list of other files) and see if your local storage contains those files. If it does - everybody's happy. If it doesn't then get the files that your manifest lists onto your local storage.

Don't use the code as mentioned above directly. Use some UI feedback to tell the user that you're downloading some files (and preferably ask them first in case they want to swap to wifi). Getting the manifest first is ok, just don't get the missing files without asking them.

I do this for my game "barcode beasties" which downloads approx 20Mb of audio assets on first run. I can also add further audio bits without having to push out a new release. Android is also clever enough to unzip zip files, but again, make sure you are telling the user what's happening and give them the ability to cancel or back without killing your main activity thread.

Comment: Richard is right, in that you should definitely add some code to show the user what you are doing.

I am actually using php to get the file on the server and I add the orig file name and the content length in the header of the response. 

I have a button to start the download in the app and when it gets hit I do the whole downloading in an `AsyncTask`. Also I show a `ProgressDialog` and first reader the header info to get the content length so I have a progress bar. 

The code in my answer is just an example - but definitely not complete.

Comment: I need the user to be able to select individual files to download as they wish, i know the manifest file could be used for version control but again, im trying to learn so i dont really know if I could make it work with being able to select each individual file to download

Comment: I think you're asking too much in one question - you probably need to break it down so that you can get all the constituent bits and glue them together. Sounds as if you need 1) file compare / version control 2) android checkbox / list to select the changed ones 3) async download. I'm sure if you ask for some examples then you'll finally get one. I would cut and paste mine but its not exactly what you want (especially with the individual selection).

Comment: any chance of ticking the box that says "this is the acceptable answer??"

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a standard `HttpUrlConnection` on the android site and just give it a `URL` that points to your zip File on the server.

Then you can just download it to a local folder on the device. 
Here is an example for how I download Excel files (zip and excel files are both binary - so it should be the same).

When you want to do some sort of version control you are probably better off doing this on the server side (if possible) with whatever the server offers (e.g. php). 
Then make a small php script that checks the version of the available zip files and send a response (maybe a json response).

```
        URL url = new URL("yourURL");

        HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpConnection.connect();


        InputStream input = httpConnection.getInputStream();

        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File(activity
                .getFilesDir().getPath() + "/" + "yourFileName.zip"));

        byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];

        int len1 = 0;
        int bytesWritten = 0;
        while ((len1 = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, len1);
            bytesWritten += len1;
        }

        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
```

Comment: could i use json to check the contents of a manifest file on both devices?

Comment: What technology is available on the server side?

Comment: That I have or that is available?